# How to write forward_difference function in Python?

Tags: python

Write a function ***forward_difference*** which takes a function f:R→R and returns another real-valued function defined by ***forward_difference(f)(x)=f(x+1)−f(x)***.

I want to write some codes by Python. How can I do it? Perhaps the first line is

```
def forward_difference(f):
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The key observation is that in Python you can define a function inside another function. A new function object is created each time `forward_difference` is called.

Furthermore, the inner function can access the variables from the invocation of the outer function in which it was created (in this case what matters is the argument, `f`).

```
def forward_difference(f):
    def difference_func(x):
        return f(x+1) - f(x)
return difference_func
```

Each separate `difference_func` has its own version of `f`.

For an example this simple, you could even use a lambda instead of a named inner function:

```
def forward_difference(f):
    return lambda x : f(x+1) - f(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward, the translation from the English description of your problem to code is about as direct as you could hope for:

```
def forward_difference(f):
    def new_func(x):
        val = f(x + 1) - f(x)
        return val
    return new_func
```

Using it:

```
g = lambda x: x ** 2
g_fd = forward_difference(g)
g_fd(1)
Out[5]: 3
```